# How can I show different icons in the task bar and app window?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have a number of apps written in C++, some of which are MFC apps and MFC Dialog apps.

I have two icons which I need to show. One icon is for the main window of an app, the second icon is for the Windows Taskbar. I can easily set the main window app using `WM_SETICON`. However, this is also changing the icon I see in the Taskbar.

Each app has the "standard" icon in the exe. That is the icon I see in Explorer and TaskManager when the app is running. I see the EXE's icon in the Taskbar if I don't send `WM_SETICON`. But, if I send `WM_SETICON`, it changes the icon on the main window AND in the Taskbar.

How can I still set the main window's icon without changing the icon in the Taskbar?

I think I can do this if I register a window class and give the class the icon I want to see in the app's main window. But, MFC (especially dialog apps) registers the window classes and gives them a generic MFC icon. So, using `WM_SETICON` appears to be my only way to change the icon in the main window.

Answer (score 0):

The taskbar displays a list of applicable windows (un-owned, not tool windows etc.), not processes.

From old [MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20020404063054/http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/shellcc/platform/shell/programmersguide/shell_int/shell_int_programming/taskbar.asp):

> The Shell creates a button on the taskbar whenever an application creates a window that isn't owned. To ensure that the window button is placed on the taskbar, create an unowned window with the WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended style. To prevent the window button from being placed on the taskbar, create the unowned window with the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW extended style. As an alternative, you can create a hidden window and make this hidden window the owner of your visible window.

Older Delphi/C++ builder based applications [used](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MainFormOnTaskBar) a "hidden" (still WS_VISIBLE?) window as the owner of its application windows (forms). This design allows you to have a different taskbar icon. The downside of this design is possible issues with taskbar thumbnails/preview and you might have to manually deal with some minimize/restore and focus events.

Having a different icon in the taskbar would just be confusing for users, I recommend that you don't fight Windows on this, just accept the behavior...

See also:

- [Should all windows appear in the taskbar?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070117-01/?p=28373)
- [Why does the taskbar icon for grouped windows change to something weird?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150812-00/?p=91831)

Comment: Thanks Anders but I know that. MFC apps already create the app window and sending the WM_SETICON messages (for large and small icons) effects the change in both the title bar and the task bar. I only want to change the icon in the title bar while keeping the icon one sees in Explorer or TaskManager as the icon in the task bar. I would like to do so without taking over the drawing of the non-client area (title bar) as I have to do this for a good number of apps, regardless of whether it will confuse some users. Our two icons are created to avoid confusion and I have already lost that battle.

Comment: MFC is irrelevant. If you want this behavior your visible app window needs an owner so it does not appear in the taskbar. This owner window will be the taskbar button. Delphi already moved away from this design for a reason...

Comment: MFC is relevant in that I don't call RegisterClassEx. And, I want an icon in the app bar. MFC creates the dialog app window when DoModal is called. The parent is the desktop when that occurs. OnInitDialog is my first chance to send WM_SETICON. Creating another "owner/parent" window is fraught with perils and unknowns so I hope to avoid that. I'm guessing alt-tab and other window navigation will show issues I would have to address. My MDI app will probably also start showing issues too. NC painting might be my only option.

Comment: @RDH Anders is correct. You are not getting the result you want because your main window is acting as the owner of the Taskbar button, so they will use the same icon. The ONLY way to achieve the result you want (without custom drawing) is to NOT put the main window on the Taskbar at all, create ANOTHER window to act as the main window's owner (not its parent), and then you can have different icons assigned to each window separately. Whether or not you can achieve this with MFC, I have no clue. But it shouldn't affect your ability to use MDI in your main window. But yes, it will affect Alt-Tab.

Comment: Sorry but something else is going on. This was working and then quit working. Today, someone got a new/clean machine and installed our app and ... my two icons are different (again). So, I asked him to get an image of both icons. I'd show you the image if I can figure out how to paste it in, I'd show you. Just a call to WM_SETICON is all I'm doing.